# ASP.net Custom GridView Control

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, user-controls, asp.net-2.0

I'm working on a custom GridView control and need some help. I can get it to properly spit out what I need if I manually put in the column name. Right now I have 2 problems. The first one is getting the column headers to display dynamically. The second is filling in row items dynamicly.

Default.aspx

```
<asp:View id="vCreateNew" runat="server">
            Content Here (View 2)...
            <trac:DataGridView id="gvMain" runat="server"  GridLines="Horizontal"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" > </trac:DataGridView>
        </asp:View>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class processes_ProgramTrack_Default
    Inherits Citi.CSPaper.Controls.BasePage
    Protected Sub ProgramTrackNav_MenuItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles ProgramTrackNav.MenuItemClick
        Dim strSelection As String = ProgramTrackNav.SelectedValue
        Dim sqlDataSource As New SqlDataSource()
        sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CSPaperWEBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Select Case strSelection
            ......                
            Case "CreateNew"
                mlvNav.SetActiveView(vCreateNew)
                sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ProgramNumber], [ProgramName], [ProgramStatus] FROM tblPrgTrackPrograms"
                Dim args As New DataSourceSelectArguments
                gvMain.DataSource = sqlDataSource.Select(args)
                gvMain.DataBind()
            ........
            End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

GridViewControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="GridViewControl.ascx.vb"  Inherits="GridViewControl" %>
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewControl" runat="server" >
</asp:GridView>
```

GridViewControl.ascx.vb

```
Public Class GridViewControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Private _html As New StringBuilder()
    Private _dataSource As IEnumerable
    Private _CssClass As String
    Private _CellSpacing As String
    Public Property DataSource() As IEnumerable
        Get
            Return _dataSource
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As IEnumerable)
            _dataSource = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overridable Property CssClass() As String
        Get
            Return _CssClass
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _CssClass = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overridable Property CellSpacing() As String
        Get
            Return _CellSpacing
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _CellSpacing = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Sub CreateBulletedList()
        Dim dataSource As IEnumerable = Nothing
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim strArr() As String = {"ID", "Name", "Fee"}
        Try
            dataSource = Me._dataSource
        Catch
        End Try

        If Not (dataSource Is Nothing) Then
            _html.Append("<table id=""" & ClientID & """ class=""" & _CssClass & """ CellSpacing=""" & _CellSpacing & """>")
            _html.Append("<thead>" & vbCrLf & "<tr>" & vbCrLf)
            For Each Item As String In strArr
                _html.Append("<th>" & Item & "</th>" & vbCrLf)
            Next
            _html.Append("</tr>" & vbCrLf & "</thead><tbody>" & vbCrLf)
            For Each dataObject As Object In dataSource
                _html.Append("<tr>" & vbCrLf)
                For i = 0 To 2
                    _html.Append("<td>" & vbCrLf)
                    _html.Append(dataObject.Row(i))
                    _html.Append("</td>" & vbCrLf)
                Next
                _html.Append("</tr>" & vbCrLf)
            Next dataObject
            _html.Append("</tbody></table>" & vbCrLf)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub DataBind()
        MyBase.OnDataBinding(EventArgs.Empty)

        CreateBulletedList()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal output As HtmlTextWriter)
        output.Write(_html)
    End Sub
End Class

------------------------------------
| Table Data                       |
------------------------------------
ID  AppName            Environment
2   TestApp            UAT
3   ServerFileMaint    UAT
4   ProgramTrack       Development
5   RegZ_Stmnt_Adj     Active
6   SecInv             Decommission
```

I do not want to manually code `for i = 0 to ...`, the upperbound, but want to do this dynamicly. Same way for the headings. The problem I run into is if I don't hard code the upperbound I get an error message stating `Cannot find column 3.`. I get this when coding a second `For Each` block to loop through the row contained data.

Comment: Did you have the chance to try my code out? Or did you take an alternate route?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand whats going on here, and how to fix it.

The biggest source of confusion for me is this block:

```
            For Each dataObject As Object In dataSource
                _html.Append("<tr>" & vbCrLf)
                For i = 0 To 2
                    _html.Append("<td>" & vbCrLf)
                    _html.Append(dataObject.Row(i))
                    _html.Append("</td>" & vbCrLf)
                Next
                _html.Append("</tr>" & vbCrLf)
            Next dataObject
```

If dataSource is a DataSet then this kind of makes sense... but not really because instead you would want to reference Table(0).  If dataSource is a DataTable then this kind of makes sense except not really because then you would want to loop through `For Each dataObject as DataRow in dataSource.Rows`.  This doesn't appear to be the case though because you reference dataObject.Row(i).

What you probalby want to do is (in rough/untested code) more like this:

```
            For Each dataObject As DataRow In dataSource.Rows
                _html.Append("<tr>" & vbCrLf)
                For Each col as DataColumn In dataSource.Columns
                    _html.Append("<td>" & vbCrLf)
                    _html.Append(dataObject(col).ToString())
                    _html.Append("</td>" & vbCrLf)
                Next
                _html.Append("</tr>" & vbCrLf)
            Next
```

This makes the assumption that dataSource is a DataTable, you are going to loop through all of that tables rows, and then for each row you will loop through all columns in the datatable and get the data in that row for each column and display it.